# UBUNTU 10.04 64 vlan not passing traffic for 32 sec

Tags: ubuntu, vlan

So here is my problem I have a server running Ubuntu 10.04 64x. there is one nic in the server. When I set up vlans on the nic with or with out static ip addresses. The vlans will not forward traffic for 32sec. I have set up Portfast on my switch. And still have this problem looking at it with. Anyone have any ideas.

Comment: What kind of switch do you have and what is the exact command you used to setup portfast? This is almost definitely the time it takes spanning tree to converge.

Comment: It is a Cisco 2960. command is (spanning-tree portfast) and I have the port set up as a trunk. All vlan are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The `spanning-tree portfast` command will only work on non-trunk ports. You should have gotten a response like this when you issued the command:

> %Portfast has been configured on X/X but will only have effect when the interface is in a non-trunking mode.

You should also see this when you check the settings with the `show spanning-tree interface X/X portfast`.

The command you want is `spanning-tree portfast trunk`.

Comment: I will give it a try when I get to work. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you I completely space that command. we do not use it in my comp because it would cause problems in our environment. But it will work in my lab.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a bridge? Then try adding `bridge_maxwait 0` to your bridge configuration (usually in `/etc/network/interfaces`).

Comment: It is just a trunk with vlans on it no bridge.